# Create udev rules to assign names to physical usb ports?

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, udev

I want to use a udev rule to assign a name (or symlink) accroding to the physical usb ports regardless of the machine that is there. The "why" is below in the tl;dr.

Here's what's in my *10-local.rules* for my raspberry pi. (EDIT: Current rules)

```
KERNELS=="1-1.2:1.0", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", SYMLINK+="Row1_Machine1"
```

I tried doing a SYMLINK but that didn't work either.

Edit: Ran Udevadm Test and it yelled at me and said that it can't rename it. Fine. So I switched back to SYMLINK and it gave the following permission denied error when I ran the test:

```
Invalid inotify descriptor    
ttyACM0: Failed to create symlink '/dev/Row1_Machine1.tmp-c166:0' to 'ttyACM0': Permission denied
```

tl;dr: I'm running four instances of octoprint servers to control my 3D printers which are connected by USB. From my workstation I want to be able to see which row, and what machine (spot 1, 2 3, or 4) I'm accessing. I cannot do attributes of the specific machines because they get swapped out all the time when they break down. I want the cord that runs to row 1, space 1 to ALWAYS report as that name regardless of what machine is swapped into that location.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out those settings worked, I just needed to restart. Now that the symlink is made I just need to see why octoprint won't show it on the list of available. Off to the next crisis! Thank you lurking viewers!